# Set WooCommerce product attribute via query string parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product that needs to include a referral token in an attribute of the product. The referral code will be in a query string parameter. The idea is to have this referral token captured in the product data so that it can at least be viewed in the order details that an admin has access to. For example..

Product URL is: `test.com/product/my-product?referral_token=12345`

I already have an attribute created that is named Referral Token and is set to 000 by default.

Using `print_r($product->get_attributes());` returns the following..

```
Array
(
    [referrer-token] => WC_Product_Attribute Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0
                    [name] => Referrer Token
                    [options] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 000
                        )

                    [position] => 0
                    [visible] => 
                    [variation] => 
                )

        )

)
```

When viewing the URL above how can I set the referrer-token attribute to be the value from the `referral_token` query string parameter that equals `12345`? I'm also open to any other suggestions as to how to attach this referral token to the product.

Comment: You don't have to add the data to the product, you have to add it to order data. Does adding this referrral_token to just the order solves your problem, or you necessarily have to add it to the product, because it doesn't make sense to update product data on every order.

Comment: Adding it to the order would be fine. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: It could be very straight forward, when someone hits your product page with query parameter, save it to its users session. Once you have done that, on every successful order check if the session has this token or not, if it has the token then save it as order meta. YOu can see the code for saving meta here : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/saving-custom-meta-automatically-when-an-order-is-placed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up from my comments on your question you can do them like this.

Set Session value when query parameter is present

```php
// Run this on product page and when the query parameter is there
$woocommerce->session->set( '_referral_token', '1234XYZ' );
```

Use `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook to trigger the save the token.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou','save_referal_after_order_completion', 10, 1 );

function save_referal_after_order_completion($order_id) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $referral= $woocommerce->session->get( '_referral_token' );

   if($referral) {
     $order->update_meta_data( '_referral', $referral);
     $order->save();
     $woocommerce->session->__unset( '_referral' ); // Remove session when done.
   }

}
```